# Add a trait to parametric type in a class

Tags: scala, generics, traits, parametric-polymorphism

I have a library where an `abstract class Base[T]` is over a type `T` supplied by the user. There are many specific `Base[T]` sub-classes, some are over types `T` and `S`, like `Specific[T, S]`, but this is irrelevant. The user might specify any `T` of course while creating and instance, but I want to treat it as `T` with a trait `AdditionalAbilities` or in other words I want to 'gift' the user's type with `AdditionalAbilities`. How can I do that in Scala? I hope the title is correct for this question.

Example (might not be syntactically correct)

```
class Specific[T **with trait Additional**]() extends Base[T](){
  def doSomething() : T = {
    val something = new T()
    something.ability(2)
    println(something.additional)
    something
  }
}

trait Additional{
  var additional : Integer

  def ability(i : Integer) : Unit = {
    additional = i
  }
}
```

Would work with any `T`.

Comment: Can you provide a somewhat more concrete example of what these trait should look like, and what should be inherited?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I've added a little example.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a parametric class you can require the parameter type to descend from a certain type:

```
trait AdditionalAbilities {
  def doStuff(): Unit = println("Hey There")
}

object NoAbility extends AdditionalAbilities {
  override def doStuff(): Unit = ()
}

abstract class Base[T] { ... }

class Specific[T <: AdditionalAbilities] extends Base[T] {
  def f(t: T): Unit = t.doStuff()
}
```

Then when you try to instantiate a `Specific` type:

```
scala> new Specific[Int] {}
<console>:13: error: type arguments [Int] do not conform to class Specific's type parameter bounds [T <: AdditionalAbilities]

scala> val b = new Specific[NoAbility.type] {}
b: Specific[NoAbility.type] = $anon$1@517cd4b

scala> b.f(NoAbility)
//did nothing
```

Also, if you want to add a behaviour to an existing concrete class, you can do so at the time of instantiation:

```
trait CoolAbilities { def doStuff(): Unit = println("Hey there") }
class A { }

scala> val a = new A with CoolAbilities
a: A with CoolAbilities = $anon$1@6ad3381f

scala> a.doStuff()
Hey there
```

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to get it work with `Int` without extending explicitly?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for type classes then?  Here is a good introduction to do type classes in Scala: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html

Comment: So if I understand correclty you would like to be able to have the trait `AdditionalAbilities` automatically mixed in with the Int type when I instantiate a new Base[Int] ? basically same as if the user would do new Base[Int with AdditionalAbilities] ? But you want to do that inside the Base class and not when the user instantiate ?

Comment: Yes! I've looked into type classes, but I guess they're not feasable for this problem.

Comment: One thing you could do is when instantiating a concrete class `A`, you can always mix in traits: `val aWithAbilities = new A() with AdditionalAbilities`. Assuming `AdditionalAbilities` does not define abstract member that would instantiate an A with the methods of AdditionalAbilities. However you can only instantiate a class when you have the concrete type, you cannot do that if it is a type parameter as you don't have access to the constructor.

Comment: Hm, actually, this workaround might be a fix for me. Any issues I can hang into while doing this? Or is there any other approaches? Can you please, update your answer?

Comment: I edited my response to reflect our discussion, I added a section on how to mix in a trait on a concrete class. But the issue I can see there is that you will not be able to instantiate a type given as a parameter in `class Specific[T]`, since you cannot do a `new T` from that abstract type.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps implicit classes could help? Implicit classes allow you to add functionality to an existing type without needing to modify the existing type, or be the one instantiating it (so that you could mix in a trait).

The following compiles, and prints: 3

```
class Specific[T] {
  implicit class TAdditional(t: T) {
    var additional: Integer = 0
    def ability(i: Integer) = {
      additional = i
    }
  }

  def doSomething(t: T) = {
    doSomethingAdditional(t)
  }

  private def doSomethingAdditional(t: TAdditional) = {
    t.ability(3)
    println(t.additional)
  }
}

val s = new Specific[Int]
s.doSomething(5)
```

Note: We need to do something to make sure we are accessing the same instance
of TAdditional, that's why I made the private doSomethingAdditional method that takes a TAdditional as an argument. If we call ability and additional in 'doSomething', separate instances of TAdditional would be created when we try to access #ability and #additional, and '0' would be printed.